# Using Klocwork for .Net static code analyses

Tags: klocwork

Currently I am using `Parasoft® dotTEST™` for  .NET Static Analysis.
Can I use `Klocwork` for .NET code `(including C#, VB.NET, ASP.NET and Managed C++ )`  static code analyses ?

Answer (score 1):

Klockwork doesn't support VB.NET while Parasoft does, in general Parasoft is better .NET analysis tool with much more .NET "checkers" and dynamic analysis features that Klockwork don't have. You need to add the Parasoft  C++TEST module to the dotTEST module that you alredy have and then you can check unmanged C++ as well, in previous versions managed C++ was supported in dotTEST but I'm not sure about the current version 9.5

Answer (score 0):

Klocwork currently (9.6 release) supports C# analysis for .NET, up to the C# 3.0 specification.  VB.NET, ASP.NET and Managed C++ are not supported.  The current list of supported C# checkers is here:
http://www.klocwork.com/products/documentation/current/C-sharp_checker_reference

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the v. 6.00 PVS-Studio also supports C# http://www.viva64.com/en/b/0362/ . They have already checked Roslyn and found some bugs.